# Creating a Mac/Windows App That Can Communicate With Serial Ports

Tags: qt, serial-port, cross-platform, qt5

I'm looking to create software that can run on OSX and Windows that will send commands to a device attached to a serial port.

My first though was to use Adobe Air, but there is not native serial port library I can use, I'd have to package the app with serproxy or something similar and then it would get complicated to setup.

I came across something called Qt that looks like it would be a suitable framework, however, I'd need to learn a new language to get going with it. (Which isn't necessarily a problem). Is Qt my best option?
Are there any frameworks that have inbuilt serial libraries that would allow me to build in HTML/CSS JavaScript? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Qt is a good choice, and there's an add-on for the Qt5 library at http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort that is used for communicating with serial ports.

Answer (score 2):

Real Studio has a built-in [Serial](http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/Serial) class that can be used to communicate with serial and compatible USB devices. And Real Studio can create Windows and OS X apps of course.